# Failure to create a SqlDataSourceEnumerator

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Collections;

namespace Tinkering_with_SqlDataSourceEnumerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run this code, the system gives the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'SqlDataSourceEnumerator' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Sql' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What am I doing wrong? Curiously, an application that was included with a programming textbook launches without problems, at least it does not produce this error message, and the term `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` is not underscored red in **Visual Studio**

I wanted to create an instance of `SqlDataSourceEnumerator`, similarly to the code provided on the [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.instance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Sql_SqlDataSourceEnumerator_Instance) about this object.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my question. I wanted to create an instance, similarly to the code provided on the MSDN website.

Comment: What are you enumerating through?  Tables in the database, Columns in a table, or rows in a table?

Comment: @jdweng - I just wanted to get the list of all available SQL servers in the system, similarly to what is told on the MSDN page.

Comment: Is your project using a version of ".NET Framework"? As far as I know it's not available in .NET Core.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - probably! I'm using Visual Studio 16.4.2. I'm not an expert)) In another project that I have, this line causes no problems.

Comment: I think you really want the Databases in one server.  Use GetSchema.  See : https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-schemas-in-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Supported Platforms: .NET Framework
>   4.8 4.7.2 4.7.1 4.7 4.6.2 4.6.1 4.6 4.5.2 4.5.1 4.5 4.0 3.5 3.0 2.0  Xamarin.Android
>   7.1  Xamarin.iOS 
>   10.8  Xamarin.Mac 
>   3.0

Try changing target platform for your project.

Comment: Any options for enumerating SQL Instances where changing the target platform is not an option?  I'm using .Net Core 3.1.  Surely .Net Core has a method for this absolutely essential function...

Answer (score 4):

This has finally been moved into the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` library: [SqlClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlclientfactory.createdatasourceenumerator?view=sqlclient-dotnet-2.1)

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately when I try it, `CreateDataSourceEnumerator()` always returns null, which I think is because I'm using .NET 6.0. So for anyone trying this solution, you can check the property `CanCreateDataSourceEnumerator` first to see if it will work for you. Still, at least now I know I probably need to look for a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not a direct replacement for SqlDataSourceEnumerator. Until the SQLClient team addresses the missing api you could try a Udp solution.

This repo is targetted at .Net5, but should work just fine on .NetCore

https://github.com/mrsquish/SqlBrowserClient

Answer (score 0):

It is now in `Microsoft.Data.Sql`

Comment: You might want to add a few more details (since when/which version was it moved? IS there an official source/documentation?)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35404325)